# where there isn't a vessel available for washing with is there another option available for someone to eat bread?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, eating, bread

where there isn't a vessel available for washing with is there another option available for someone to eat bread? Or said another way if the only option for washing my hands is the sink but no cup available what's the proper procedure if any to be able to consume bread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is subject to a dispute among modern day poskim if the faucet has a din of a kli. Rav Elyashiv and Rav Ovadia Yosef both held it did have a din of a kli; thus, if no cup is available, one can turn the faucet on and off twice (or three if Sephardic) on each hand, since turning on the faucet is considered "koach gavra".

This is not to be relied upon practically: ask a rav personally.

Comment: Sink water may be mikva water anyway, so worth closing the drain at the bottom.

Comment: You only need to wash once per hand if you use a reviit (as most everyone does) and I don't know what Sefardim have to do with anything.

Comment: see pertinent shulchan aruch hilchos netilas yadayim for the reason why we wash more than once (lehasir hatuma)

Comment: Was that a comment to me? I am talking about pertinent shulchan aruch hilchos netilas yadayim. It says you only need to wash once per hand if you use a reviit (as most everyone does) just like I said above. What are you talking about?

Comment: I recently remembered this question I had and was able to ask a rav. He gave this answer.

Comment: Rav Eliyashiv does not hold its a kli

Comment: Regarding R' Elyashiv, see @sam 's answer [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67216).

Comment: @sam Rav Webber from neve Yaakov, a close student of R Elyashiv quoted R Elyashiv that he held that pipes have a din kli, to the extent that the faucet is a kli sheini. Which obviously have implications for kashrus and shabbos

Comment: Did you hear this from Rav Weber yourself ?

Comment: @sam yes. Regarding the kli sheini aspect he said he wouldn't pasken based off of it lekulah

Comment: Very intresting, wonder why two different psakim

Answer (score 4):

See: http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/washing-hands-on-go.html

> One can dip one’s hands into a body of water that would otherwise be suitable as a mikvah. One may wash with other liquids, if necessary, though without a Bracha. (Shulchan Aruch 160:12)
>
> While disposable cups are not ideal, one can use them if that’s all one has. Likewise, one may use a bottle, providing the water comes out in an uninterrupted flow (Mishna Berura 162:30).