# How to wash for bread when there's water but no kli?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing

I've heard that if one has no Keli for netilat yadayim before eating bread, one can just be careful to not touch the bread, for example to use a napkin. Though is it acceptable to simply wash ones hand in a faucet wothout a kli?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.163.2?lang=bi&with=Mishneh%20Torah,%20Blessings&lang2=en

Comment: Possible dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38936/27180

Comment: Shmuel the beginning of the question is a bit of a curveball, the question itself is certainly a dupe

Answer (score 0):

[Rav Ovadiah Yosef](https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=2298&PageIndex=8) brings a novel argument that in a home or building where water is piped onto a large tank on the roof (as is common in many places) and then through the faucet, the water tank itself constitutes a kli, and so one can use the faucet for natilat yadayim for bread b'diavad.This practice is necessarily b'diavad because the faucet is somewhat removed from the kli.

He applies the same din to the hot water faucet in a setting without a rooftop water tank since a hot water tank is also a kli, and while l'chathila one does natilat yadayim with cold water, the whole situation is already b'diavad to begin with